# Why THIS example?

Tags: discussion

Was about to post a new question, and noticed that on the tag-entry field the example says to include *at least one tag* such as "thriller the-dark-knight-rises character." Shouldn't the example be **ONE** tag, instead of three, and one a little less vague? I *did* see the movie, was not impressed, and don't remember the character "Thriller." I DO remember the lozenge-deficient character Bane... And the main character Batdance (although that might be from the 1989 version).

I posit we should use a more recognizable **single** tag as an example.

If the example is culling from a random pile, it's not working well. Three refreshes still pulled that example.

Comment: I **DON'T** recommend identify-this as an example because so many people here (not me) dislike those questions. Rosebud, batman, the-avengers, box-office, twister-1989, the-simpsons, subtitles, etc... There are **SO MANY** better examples.

Comment: Yet, what is *"better"*? I've never seen *The Avengers*, nor *Batman*, I hate *The Simpsons* and *Twister*. I don't care about box office stuff. And what the hell's rosebud? I get what you're saying, but you're refuting it with your supposedly *"better"* examples really.

Answer (score 1):

The tags shown in that example when creating a question are [chosen from a pool of eligible tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-are-suggested-tags-chosen).

There are three examples, it's not recommending that you use multiple, it's requiring that you use at least one. [It has been mentioned before by some people that these should be delimited with a comma](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185336/distinguish-suggested-tags-with-a-comma-when-asking-a-new-question) but I believe it is behaving as designed.

Comment: Still seems unnecessarily confusing. While this probably wouldn't drive anyone away by itself, a lot of new people also confuse us with a discussion forum. It seems like our examples should be a little more concise. Especially if there are only three. I love movies and don't remember Thriller. Eschew obfuscation and all that.

Comment: Fortunately, new users are greeted by [the "Take a Tour" banner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217061/229699) - while we can't force people to read, we always have the ability to close stuff that ignores the site rules. I'm not saying it's perfect, that's partially why we're [working on simplifying the way we use tags](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1733/5603)

Comment: Didn't know we had a new banner, sorry. I'm not here as much as I'd like to be anymore, but I love this place, and may get no takers. [Way of the road.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb0bwbcfd28) Still, I stand by my opinion that's it not a good example. (Fighting the urge to Google the example so I'm still pure in this topic... Must... Fight... Satan...)

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is to give examples of 3 different types of tags -- in this case: genre (thriller), movie name (The Dark Knight Rises), and movie element (character) -- **so that the first-time questioner realizes there are several different types of tags that might apply to his/her question**.

Comment: That sounds nice and like a good idea. But I still think they're entirely random. I doubt the algorithm knows about any semantic characterizations. Where would this information even come from, there are no tag categories? (I just got `interstellar`, `production`, `the-dark-knight-rises`. But it sure seems to love `the-dark-knight-rises`, most probably based on question count.)